# Converting batch (.bat) script to bash or python

Tags: python, bash, batch-file

So i have the following batch script that needs to be converted to bash or python, preferably python.  But since I know bash, i wanted to convert it to  that first, then later convert the bash to python.

```
@echo off
REM Version ${project.version}

set DESTINATION_PATH=C:\Events\
set TEMP_EXTENSION=.tmp
set FINAL_EXTENSION=.txt

for /f "delims=:. tokens=1-4" %%t in ("%TIME: =0%") do (
        set FILENAME=event-%5-%%t%%u%%v%%w
    )

echo cycleNumber = %1 >> %DESTINATION_PATH%%FILENAME%%TEMP_EXTENSION%
echo runFolder = %2 >> %DESTINATION_PATH%%FILENAME%%TEMP_EXTENSION%
echo netFolder = %3 >> %DESTINATION_PATH%%FILENAME%%TEMP_EXTENSION%
echo runType = %4 >> %DESTINATION_PATH%%FILENAME%%TEMP_EXTENSION%
echo eventType = %5 >> %DESTINATION_PATH%%FILENAME%%TEMP_EXTENSION%
echo softwareType = HCS >> %DESTINATION_PATH%%FILENAME%%TEMP_EXTENSION%

rename %DESTINATION_PATH%%FILENAME%%TEMP_EXTENSION% %FILENAME%%FINAL_EXTENSION%

exit 0
```

Here is what I have so far:

```
#@echo off
set -v
#REM Version ${project.version}
# ${project.version}

#set DESTINATION_PATH=C:\Events\
#set TEMP_EXTENSION=.tmp
#set FINAL_EXTENSION=.txt

export DESTINATION_PATH=/blah/Events
export TEMP_EXTENSION=".tmp"
export FINAL_EXTENSION=".txt"
```

I used this site to help me figure out what the equivalent symbol would be in bash:

http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/dosbatch.html

Now I'm stuck and dont know how to interpret the for loop or the rest of the .bat script.  I'm not quite sure my interpretation so far is correct.  Please advise.

Comment: Does using `curr_time=$(date "+%H%M%S%2N")` or similar then appending `$curr_time` to your string not simplify the process of trying to convert a batch hack which doesn't require hacking in bash!

Comment: Translating from one programming language to another is generally not a good idea (especially, if you do it line by line / command by command). Doing it twice usually doesn't make things better. Better analyze, what the program in language A does and create it from scratch in language B. The shown code is pretty straightforward, so it shouldn't be a big issue.

Comment: Write a specification of the `.bat` script first (unless of course you already have one), then implement it in `bash`.  As @Stephan says, its a lost cause trying to translate line-by-line.